# Show/Hide Child Nodes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show child nodes(If option selected is 'Yes') based on the indent value. `indent0-> parent node` , `indent1 - child node`. 
Sort-order is the order in which nodes are placed in DB.

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".js-show-aspects", function(event) {
    var displayLabel = $(this).data('meta-value');     
    var sort_order = $('.js-data-selector.active:first').data('sort-order');
    var indent = $('.js-data-selector.active:first').data('indent');
    var rowCount = $('#show_aspects td').length;

    for (var i=0;i<rowCount;i++)
    {
        var hasindent0 =$(this).next().hasClass("indent0");
        if((displayLabel=='Yes') && (hasindent0== false)) {
            child1 = $("table tr td").filter(function() {
                return $(this).prop("class").match(/indent/)});

                child = child1.addClass(function (index){ return "sort-order"+(sort_order+1)});
        }               
    }
});
```

---

HTML 
In the below html, $aspects gets all the nodes from DB,

```
<tbody>
    <? foreach($aspects as $a) { ?> 
        <tr id="show_aspects" class="js-data-selector 
            <?=($a['active'] == 0) ? "text-warning" :""; ?> "
            data-sort-order="<?= $a['sort_order'] ?>"
            data-indent="<?= $a['indent']?>" align="left"
            data-taxonomy-id="<?=$a['taxonomy_id']?>">

             <td class="indent<?=$a['indent']?> 
                 sort-order<?=$a['sort_order']?>"
                 data-indent="<?= $a['indent']?>">

                 <? if($a['active'] == 0) { 
                     echo '<strong class="pull-right text-warning">Inactive</strong>';
                 } ?>

                 <?=$a['aspect_label']?> : 
                 <span class="aspect-data" data-taxonomy-id="<?=$a['taxonomy_id']?>"></span>

             </td>
        </tr>
    <?}?>
</tbody>
```

But I am unable to get the child nodes displayed. Any idea how to sort this out?

Edited the question with the HTML content..

Comment: We can't help without seeing the DOM structure you're meant to be working with. But at a minimum, the `child1 =...` and `child =...` lines don't look right. For one thing, as far as we can tell from the above, they're undeclared vars and so falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Also, `$(this).prop("class").match(/indent/)` will match any class with `indent` anywhere in it (including, say, `indentation`); regex is overkill for a simple substring match. `child` will just be the same jQuery obj as `child1`. Etc.

Comment: this looks way too overengineered. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Edited the question with  DOM structure as well..

Comment: I am trying to loop through the sortorder - and when a class with indent0 is met,  display the rows till next indent0 is encountered.

Comment: Replace your HTML with what's generated by the browser, rather than a load of PHP code.

Comment: clean your code, there too much un-need code

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to do with the question in its current form, but if you want to hide or show child nodes with jQuery, it can be done with `$("#id").children().hide();` and `$("#id").children().show();`.
(Where "#id" is the ID of the parent DOM node.)

`children()` also takes a selector as an argument in case you only want specific children hidden/shown: http://api.jquery.com/children/

(If you clear up your question a bit, it would be possible to give a more appropriate answer)